# Mongo Spark Connector write .options(replaceDocument,false) giving exception

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark

When I try to write a large number of documents from spark to mongo using the **option** `replace document` **false**. I get the following exception while writing:-

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 28 in stage 18.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 28.3 in stage 18.0 (TID 275, 10.80.102.83, executor 2): com.mongodb.MongoBulkWriteException: Bulk write operation error on server 10.80.100.73:27017. Write errors: [BulkWriteError{index=0, code=9, message=''$set' is empty. You must specify a field like so: {$set: {<field>: ...}}', details={ }}].
```

Environment

mongo spark connectorversion :- **2.2.2**

spark version:-**2.3.1**

programming language:-**java**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the things which you need to try while dealing with spark is explore the Dataframe(there may be some values in the Dataframe which won't allow the entire operation to go through).

As the exception suggests the **option** "replace document false"  in the write config internally calls the **$set** method of mongo(***for every row in the Dataframe***).

The $set ***method does not take null as an argument*** that is why the spark write operation failed whenever it encountered a null value.

Solution:- Remove the null values from the Dataframe before writing to mongo

```
    dataFrame.na().drop()
```