# Using Spark, is there a way to bulk unset a field in Mongo documents?

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark

I have a scala Spark application that I would like to unset the fields for all documents in a Mongo collection before I load updated data into the collection.

Let's say I have a data source like this and I want to remove the "rank" field from all documents (some may have this field and some may not).

```
[
  { 
    "_id": 123,
    "value": "a"
  },
  { 
    "_id": 234,
    "value": "b",
    "rank": 1
  },
 ...
]
```

I know in mongo there is an [unset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) function, but I don't see any documentation in the [mongo spark connector](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/current/scala/write-to-mongodb/) on how to do something like this w/ Spark.

I've tried filtering out the field and dropping it in the Dataset before I save to Mongo but I run into the following error:

```
com.mongodb.MongoBulkWriteException: Bulk write operation error on server localhost:58200. Write errors: [BulkWriteError{index=0, code=9, message=''$set' is empty. You must specify a field like so: {$set: {<field>: ...}}', details={}}]. 
    at com.mongodb.connection.BulkWriteBatchCombiner.getError(BulkWriteBatchCombiner.java:173)
    ...
```

I have the following definitions:

```
case class Item(_id: Int, rank: Option[Int])

val idCol = new ColumnName("_id")
val rankCol = new ColumnName("rank")
```

and a function that does something like this in the same class:

```
def resetRanks(): {
  val records = MongoSpark
          .load[Item](
            sparkSession,
            ReadConfig(
              Map(
                "collection" -> mongoConfig.collection,
                "database" -> mongoConfig.db,
                "uri" -> mongoConfig.uri
              ),
              Some(ReadConfig(sparkSession))
            )
          )
          .select(idCol, rankCol)
          .repartition(sparkConfig.partitionSize, $"_id")
          .where(rankCol.isNotNull)
          .drop(rankCol)

  MongoSpark.save(
        records,
        WriteConfig( 
          Map(
            "collection" -> mongoConfig.collection,
            "database" -> mongoConfig.db,
            "forceInsert" -> "false", 
            "ordered" -> "true",
            "replaceDocument" -> "false", // not replacing docs since there are other fields I'd like to keep intact that I won't be modifying
            "uri" -> mongoConfig.uri,
            "writeConcern.w" -> "majority"
          ),
          Some(WriteConfig(sparkSession))
        )
      )
}
```

I'm using MongoSparkConnector v2.4.2.

I also saw this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53057901/mongo-spark-connector-write-optionsreplacedocument-false-giving-exception) which seemed to suggest the reason I get the above error is that that I can't have null fields, but I need to unset these fields so I'm at a lost on how to go about it.

Any tips or pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this where you can drop the column from the dataframe and write to a new collection. One issue I have observed here is, when trying to write to save collection, my collection was getting dropped, perhaps you can take the research from there.

Here I am directly utilizing the dataframeWriter Save function. You can use the conventional MongoSpark.save() function along with the WriteConfig as you like.

I am using Spark 3.1.2, Mongo-Spark Connector 3.0.1, Mongo 4.2.6

```
case class Item(id: Int, rank: Option[Int], value: String = "abc")

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sparkSession = getSparkSession(args)
    val items = MongoSpark.load[Item](sparkSession, ReadConfig(Map("collection" -> "items"), Some(ReadConfig(sparkSession))))
    items.show()
    val dropped = items.drop("rank")
    dropped.write.option("collection", "items-updated").mode("overwrite").format("mongo").save()
    dropped.show()
  }
```

Comment: That's an interesting idea, but recreating the collection is not an option for me since there are many fields that I'm not reading but I would like preserved in the current collection (the 'value' field was an example here). The collection size is ~100mil docs so it's not a small collection I'd like to recreate.